# Is it better to use soil and moss or just moss for a Kokedama (moss ball)?

Tags: houseplants, containers, moss, kokedama

I have come across different sources on how to make a Kokedama. A major conflict I am finding is what the Kokedama should consist of. Some suggest just wrapping the roots of the plant in moss. While others, deem it necessary to use a ball of clay-like soil wrapped in moss to contain the roots.

Is it better to use a ball of clay-like soil wrapped in moss or a ball of just moss for a Kokedama?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plant needs some growing medium in order to create roots and survive properly, so unless you're using a plant which has made a good, solid rootball in a pot first, you will need some potting soil. Most of the information I can find suggests using bonsai soil, which generally has a higher clay content anyway, and moss, see here [What Is A Kokedama: Tips On Making Kokedama Moss Balls](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/garden-how-to/projects/making-kokedama-moss-balls.htm).